# Starting to use git bash, what do these lines mean in .bash_profile?

Tags: git, bash, unix

I'm trying to learn more about git bash and shell environments and I've seen these 2 lines in my current profile. I've googled for these exact lines but I couldn't find something which explains what they do.

```
test -f ~/.profile && . ~/.profile
test -f ~/.bashrc && . ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Have you tried `man test` and (I'll admit the second one is tricky) `man bash` then search for `source` - `.` is shorthand for `source`.

Comment: The first command line could also be written `[ -f ~/.profile ] && . ~/.profile`; you might be more familiar with the `[` command which is a synonym for `test` except that it expects that its last argument will be `]` (which `test` does not).  And `source` is a longwinded way of writing `.` but is otherwise equivalent.  You could also use `if [ -f ~/.profile ]; then . ~/.profile; fi` which means the same.  And you could write the code using `[[` instead of `[`, …

Comment: The git bash I'm using on windows doesn't have a man command. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, I'm fairly new to coding so I couldn't fully understand your answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- `test -f FILE` checks if `FILE` exists and it is a file, not a directory.
- `. FILE` will execute commands from `FILE` in the current shell. It's a synonym of the builtin `source`.
- Command followed by `&&` will only execute if the previous command *exited normally*, or more technically returns 0. Otherwise, the command following `&&` will not execute.

So, `test -f ~/.profile && . ~/.profile` will check if `~/.profile` exists, and **if** it exists, it will run that file in the current shell.

Comment: `-f` will actually test if it exists and is a regular file, not a directory or block device or similar.  `-e` would just test if it exists

Answer (score 0):

`test` can be used to test various things. The `-f` switch checks for existence of a file.

So if `test -f ~/.profile` returns zero (meaning success), `~/.profile` is sourced.

You can read more on `test` on the man page: `man test`.

Comment: Thanks ronak, I don't have access to the man command on my git for windows, but your answer was helpful, do the && cause the file to be created then?

Answer (score 0):

It could be written in a more familiar way.

```
if [[ -f ~/.profile ]];then
    . /.profile
else
    :
fi

OR

if [[ -f ~/.bashrc ]]
then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi

OR

if [[ -f ~/.bashrc ]];then . ~/.bashrc;fi
```

It means if the file exists, execute it. (And if not, do nothing.)

The `else` part could be omitted here. The `:` here works like `pass` in Python. The space around `[[` and `]]` is always needed. Indentation is not mandatory in bash.